# Maze Game - Game randomly stops

Tags: python-3.x

Another problem with my maze game, it sometimes run fine but it seems like after some inputs the game just stops? Not too sure whats going on here.

```
import random
from random import randint


print("Welcome to Brandon's Maze Game",
  "You have to get 10 shields or find the exit to win",
  "Good Luck :D")


counter = 0
shields = 3
fate = randint(1,2)
direction = input("You have come to a stop, do you want to turn Left(L) or Right(R)? ")

if direction == "L":
if fate == 1:
    fate = randint(1,2)
    shields += 3
    counter += 1
    direction = input("You came across a chest, you now have " + str(shields) + " shields! What way do you want to go next? Left(L) or Right(R)? ")
if fate == 2:
    fate = randint(1,2)
    shields -= 1
    counter += 1
    direction = input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have " + str(shields) + " shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")

if direction == "R":
if fate == 1:
    fate = randint(1,2)
    shields += 3
    counter += 1
    direction = input("You came across a chest, you now have " + str(shields) + "! What way do you want to go next? Left(L) or Right(R)? ")
if fate == 2:
    fate = randint(1,2)
    shields -= 1
    counter += 1
    direction = input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have " + str(shields) + " shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")

if counter >= 5:
    print("Congratulations, you made it to the end with " + str(shields) + " shields.")

if shields == 0:
print("You lost all your shields, Game over.")
```

Please try and explain as simply as possible, i'm fairly new to python. If you can, show me the correct code but also explain why.

Comment: when the game stops, do you get any `Errors` or a `Stacktrace`?

Comment: Nope, it just puts ">>>                 " on a new line

Comment: Looks like it may stop as expected, as there are no `loops` in your program. Do some debugging on each of the `if` conditions. What are your inputs and *expected* outputs?

Comment: Also, try to correct your code indentation in the question post to better match or replicate the code you're actually running

Comment: That is how I am running it, also i want it to output whether you got a chest or got attacked.

Comment: When I run your code, I input `L` or `R` and I see that output; I get `You came across a chest,` or `Uh oh, you got attacked`. Is that not what you get? What output are you getting?

Comment: I get that output, but enter L or R again, sometimes it just ends, keep playing and you will see what i mean

Comment: correct, it just ends because that's how you've designed it. For example, after line `direction = raw_input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have " + str(shields) + " shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")`... if `counter < 5` it will exit the `if` block and there's no more code, so the program should exit. If you expect a different behavior, you'll have to add more code.

Comment: If you want it to continue checking the input, you'll probably need to put everything in a `while` loop. Put a line `while counter < 5:` before the first `if` statement, run it again and see if that's the output you're expecting

Comment: To add to @downshift 's comment, you will probably want to include the `fate = randint(1,2)` and `direction = input(..)` lines in your `while` loop, since I expect the direction the user picks and random results should change at each intersection. Maybe.